# Possible alogrithms of handling 40 clients in a single udp server

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, network-programming, udp

I am working on udp server/cient application. I want my Server to be able to handle 40 clients at a time.
Right now I am using the approach of creating one receiving thread which continuously receives data and one sending thread for sending data if required. 
Since the socket queue is large enough to buffer data from 40 clients so I am using only one receiving thread.
What might be other possible ways to implement such single server multiple client
application?

Comment: You have a solution that works.  Why do you want to change it?  You could use IOCP, if you really need to, but if your current design is OK....

Comment: Copied from another answer - Even when using UDP and unconnected sockets, you can still use functions like select. Simply bind the server socket to an address, and use that socket for select. When the socket is readable a client has sent something with e.g. sendto and you can do e.g. recvfrom.
Now the way that is ca work is that you have a "servicing thread" that has a list of all currently open sockets. It would call select, and any sockets that have new data would be filled in for you.
Here are helpful docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course run multiple server threads but each would have to listen on different UDP port. If that is fine with you try multiple threads but no more than number of processor cores you have. Anything more than that will slow the whole thing down due to threads switching.

The other thing you could try is to set the priority of your server process to real time. UDP packets are volatile - if you're too slow to catch them they are gone. This high priority brings a risk though: if your server is not properly written it can consume 100% of CPU and render system virtually hung. It should not starve other processes from CPU either, but again, if it is well written for example not using `Thread.Sleep`

But if your system works fine with current design under biggest load you can test then best thing to do is nothing.